# CRM 2011 - How to check if SystemUser is Disabled

Tags: plugins, vbscript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm writing a script (VBScript) to create/update SystemUser in the CRM by importing the required information from one of our SQL table. Everything works fine but the update of the BusinessUnitId field.

The problem is the CRM restrict the ability to do so for disabled user. And by default all my users are disabled (they serve more as contacts than user, only a few of them are actually enabled). My question is fairly simple: how do I check if the user is enabled or not ?

StateCode and StatusCode are only made to set a user to enabled or disabled. IsDisabled field in the Systemuser CRM table seems unreadable (I get an key does not exist error if I try to read from it).

I'm really stuck here. Any ideas ?

Thank you

Update 3/11/2014 (Code as requested)

```
Try 1 - Always Return True even when it should be False
If (user_new.Contains("isdisabled") And user_new.GetAttributeValue(Of Boolean)("isdisabled") = False) Then
  Console.WriteLine("ENABLED")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("DISABLED")
End If

Try 2 - Key does not exist
If (user_new.Attributes("isdisabled") = False) Then
  Console.WriteLine("ENABLED")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("DISABLED")
End If

Try 3 - Key does not exist
If (user_new.FormattedValues("isdisabled").ToString() = 0) Then
  Console.WriteLine("ENABLED")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("DISABLED")
End If
```

Comment: Can we see some of your code please?

Comment: You're not listing the most import part of your code.  How is the user_new variable being populated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BusinessUnit`, `Equipment`, `Organization`, `Resource` and `SystemUser` all use the `IsDisabled` field instead of the standard `StateCode` and `StatusCode`.  It should be stored as a boolean.  Make sure that you include it in your ColumnSet when you retrieve the SystemUser from CRM

Comment: Well, that's the thing. I am trying to get the IsDisabled value but it's always empty even though I can see it's set to 0 or 1 in the SQL table. I read somewhere that it's a non readable field, but it wasn't an official statement so I'm not sure of this.

Also, I did use StateCode and StatusCode to disable my newly created users, and that works.

Comment: @Clement show your code for retrieving the IsDisabled field.  I don't think it's non-readable.  Non-editable yes, but not non-readable.

Comment: I use this:
If user_new.Attributes("IsDisabled") = True

Comment: Which gets me a key does not exist

Comment: I also tried user_new.GetAttributeValue(Of Boolean)("isdisabled") but it always return True even when it should be False

Comment: IsDisabled was the right way to retrieve the info. My error was that I wasn't getting the IsDisabled field when retrieving my user.

Comment: @Clement That was my assumption.  Hence the "Make sure that you include it in your ColumnSet when you retrieve the SystemUser from CRM" portion of my answer